# Print custom field in Query Loop block

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, block-editor

I have added a custom field with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. I can print the content of the field on the post itself using the acf shortcode (`[acf field="date"]`) without issues.

However I also want to display this value inside a Query Loop block on a page that displays posts with this field. In this case it does not print anything.

Comment: how are you including the shortcode in the query block? What does your block look like? Do other non-ACF shortcodes work? What does ACF support say?

Comment: Same here, ACF shortcode is not working in Query Loop Block

Comment: Created an issue for this: https://github.com/AdvancedCustomFields/acf/issues/645